How to loop through and create a rollover sum in python?
Looking at the table, I am looking to replicate the Rollover column in a Python dataframe. The Rollover looks at:
Rollover is created when production > max capacity.  The following date will look at the previous day and will either add the delta of production - max capacity or will subtract the delta of max capacity - production.
Rollover will never be less than 0.


Please provide the data as text, not a picture

What dataframe library are you using, Pandas? Please add the tag for it. Or if you're open to any, just say so. Note that Python itself doesn't have dataframes. BTW if it helps, this question covers how to post your data: How to make good reproducible pandas examples

What have you tried? If you're looking for a vectorized solution, have you at least written a naive loop solution?

You can identify the index of the first time production > max_capacity, set all previous entries equal to 0, then perform a cumulative sum (rounding any negative values up to 0, see this answer). Here is a reproducible example and result:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'DATE': pd.date_range('2024-01-01','2024-01-13'),'PRODUCTION': [10,8,8,15,15,12,10,9,14,16,2,2,2],'MAX_CAPACITY':[11]*13})
df['EXTRA'] = df['PRODUCTION'] - df['MAX_CAPACITY']
first_pos_idx = df['EXTRA'].gt(0).idxmax()
df.loc[:first_pos_idx-1, "EXTRA"] = 0

## cumulative sum where negative results are rounded up to 0
sumlm = np.frompyfunc(lambda a,b: 0 if a+b < 0 else a+b,2,1)
df['ROLLOVER'] = sumlm.accumulate(df['EXTRA'].values, dtype=np.object_)

Result:
         DATE  PRODUCTION  MAX_CAPACITY  EXTRA ROLLOVER
0  2024-01-01          10            11      0        0
1  2024-01-02           8            11      0        0
2  2024-01-03           8            11      0        0
3  2024-01-04          15            11      4        4
4  2024-01-05          15            11      4        8
5  2024-01-06          12            11      1        9
6  2024-01-07          10            11     -1        8
7  2024-01-08           9            11     -2        6
8  2024-01-09          14            11      3        9
9  2024-01-10          16            11      5       14
10 2024-01-11           2            11     -9        5
11 2024-01-12           2            11     -9        0
12 2024-01-13           2            11     -9        0


OP said "Rollover will never be less than 0", but if you added more rows with production less than capacity, this code makes it go negative. For example I tried it out with two more days of production=2, which makes the rollover -4 and -13.

@wjandrea thanks for finding that, I believe I have corrected the issue now
